# какие аргументы принимает pygame.sprite.collide_rect() если спрайты записаны в переменных?

Tags: python, pygame

что писать в аргументах `pygame.sprite.collide_rect()` ?
вот переменные:

```
player=pygame.draw.rect(win,(0,0,255),(x,y,width,height))
rect=pygame.draw.rect(win,(255,0,0),(rect_x,rect_y,rect_width,rect_height))
```

как сделать реакцию на касание двух спрайтов?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нашел метод [pygame.sprite.collide_rect](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.collide_rect) в документации:

> Collision detection between two sprites, using rects.
> collide_rect(left, right) -> bool

Но он для спрайтов, а у вас там `Rect`, поэтому больше подойдет метод [pygame.Rect.colliderect](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect.colliderect)

> test if two rectangles overlap
> colliderect(Rect) -> bool

Тогда, использование должно быть таким:

```
is_collide = player.colliderect(rect)
```

Comment: я написал ```if is_collide==True:
    x=5
    y=435```
выдает ошибку: ```Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Edward\Desktop\пайтон\py.py", line 21, in <module>
    is_collide = pygame.sprite.collide_rect(player, rect)
  File "C:\Users\Edward\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pygame\sprite.py", line 1411, in collide_rect
    return left.rect.colliderect(right.rect)
AttributeError: 'pygame.Rect' object has no attribute 'rect'```

Comment: Мои ошибка, в эту функцию нужно передавать спрайты, а она внутри себя вызывает `left.rect.colliderect(right.rect)`, т.е. сама у спрайтов вызывает их размеры, подправлю код. Кст,  писать сравнение с `True` в `if is_collide==True:` излишне, можно просто `if is_collide:`

Comment: @Robot78, обновил ответ

Comment: изменил содержимое переменной `is_collide`, не реагирует на касания

Comment: Выведите те квадраты на экран и визуально смотрите где они и работает ли пересечение. Я с этим методом работал и он нормально показывает себя, пример: https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/5a780831079c69cd2351a2249d6c8397c6f27a57/pygame__examples/rect_collision.py

Comment: `if player.colliderect(rect):` выдает ошибку `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'colliderect'`

Comment: @Robot78, у вас `player` имеет значение `None`

Comment: ну теперь опять никакой реакции

Comment: @Robot78, в комментарии по ссылке выше есть ссылка на скрипт, в котором показано, что функция `colliderect` работает, а что у вас происходит непонятно, т.к. вы не прикладывали к вопросу [минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Хз, в общем, мб попробуйте поменять местами `is_collide = rect.colliderect(player)` :)

Comment: немного изменил код, все работает но при касании во время прыжка улетает вниз.

Comment: вот код прыжка:
`isJump=False
jumpCount=7
if not isJump:
            
        if keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
            isJump=True
    else:
    
        if jumpCount >= -7:
            if jumpCount<0:
                y+=(jumpCount**2)/2
                
            else:
                y-=(jumpCount**2)/2
            jumpCount-=1
        else:
            isJump=False
            jumpCount=7`

Comment: @Robot78, добавьте минимальный пример в **вопрос**, чтобы любой мог выполнить код из вопроса и увидеть проблему, чтобы помочь вам, а по этим огрызкам кода никому не охото разбираться :) И по-моему, я вам ответил на ваш вопрос (https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour), поэтому лучше мои рекомендации выполните на новом вопросе

Answer (score 0):

я использую другую систему столкновений, если хочешь её использовать, она заключается в том, что создается любая переменная, например hits потом используется

```
hits = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(1, 2, False)#1 это первый спрайт, 2 второй
for hit in hits:
    #здесь твой код
```

Если сменить False на True, спрайт второй спрайт исчезает, если False он использует твой код и проходит насквозь(у меня от отскакивает от игрока)
удачи тебе в програмирование=)